# extract structured data from text files (awk ?) : missing fields must get default value

Tags: awk, text, field, extract

(I'm working with macos).

I have 70k text files in subfolders I want to extract some data from, recursively, then – if possible – have output written in one tab delimited file for later spreadsheet processing.
Files, coming from my wiki (I use PmWiki, which saves data in [text files](https://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/PmWiki/PageFileFormat)) are formatted this way when complete (unwanted data deleted for readability) :

```
version=
agent=
author=
charset=
csum=
ctime=1041379201
description=
host=
name=Name.12
rev=3
targets=Target.1,OtherTarget.23,Target.90
text=
time=
title=My title
author:
csum:
diff:
host:
author:
csum:
diff:
```

I would like to extract data delimited with `=` for fields named `ctime name rev targets title` (5 fields).

My main issue is how to get data (keys `ctime= rev= targets= name= title=`), plus having default values when some are missing ?

I believe one has to test if each of the targeted key exists ; create it with default value if missing ; then extract the wanted fields values and finally tabulate the data.

Expected output would be tab delimited ; missing data would be named something easy to catch later on.
i.e., for full file given in example (tabs in place of spaces), output would give something like (ctime, rev, name, title, targets) :

```
1041379201 3 Name.12 my title Target.1,OtherTarget.23,Target.90
```

and, for not complete file (missing field, in line 1, is rev ; in line 2, rev and title) :

```
1041379201 XXX Name.12 my title Target.1,OtherTarget.23,Target.90
1041379201 XXX Name.12 XXX Target.1,OtherTarget.23,Target.90
```

Final project is to be able to extract data once a month, then have text file easy to use in spreadsheet, monthly updated.

My less worst attempt is something like that (yet doesn't work at all, lacking if/else condition) :

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "=" ;} /^ctime=/ {
                print $2
                next
                }
/^rev=/ {
                print $2
                next}
/^name=/ {
                print $2
                next}
/^title=/ {
                print $2
                next}
/^targets=/ {
                print $2
                next}'
```

Here it is an original PmWiki file (in that case I still would like to extract `ctime name rev targets title` (and have default values for missing fields, `ctime` and `title`) :

```
version=pmwiki-2.2.64 ordered=1 urlencoded=1
author=simon
charset=UTF-8
csum=add summary
name=Main.HomePage
rev=203
targets=PmWiki.DocumentationIndex,PmWiki.InitialSetupTasks,PmWiki.BasicEditing,Main.WikiSandbox
text=(:Summary:The default home page for the PmWiki distribution:)%0aWelcome to PmWiki!%0a%0aA local copy of PmWiki's%0adocumentation has been installed along with the software,%0aand is available via the [[PmWiki/documentation index]].  %0a%0aTo continue setting up PmWiki, see [[PmWiki/initial setup tasks]].%0a%0aThe [[PmWiki/basic editing]] page describes how to create pages%0ain PmWiki.  You can practice editing in the [[wiki sandbox]].%0a%0aMore information about PmWiki is available from [[http://www.pmwiki.org]].%0a
time=1400472661
```

**Updating my question.**

The way I posted my question may look like more complex than it is.
From this, repeated in 70k text files :

```
word1=line1
word2=line2
word3=line3
...
```

I would like to get a file collecting every `line1, line3, lineX` (for command targetting word1, word2, wordX) AND have default value in case word1=line1 or word2=line2 or wordX=lineX doesn't exist at all.

At the end, I have found something pretty close to my need with Rick Smith's answer given to [Retrieve default value with grep -e?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974017/retrieve-default-value-with-grep-e)

Comment: Is there a fixed field requirement per file, e.g. always 21 key fields like "version" or "agent" per file or do fields occur more than once per file? Is the field delimiter "=" or ":" ? Where is the field key in your 2-line example?

Comment: Regarding `by the way I don't know how to run this kind of command recursively, for current folder and subfolders` ask a separate question about that if you can't figure it out, only ask 1 question at a time.

Comment: Editing my question for better understanding : I'm willing to collect only a few fields in each file (ctime=, rev=, name=, title=, targets=), and need to have default value for missing fields (among the five). For those fields, delimiter is always =

Comment: each input file is collapsed down to a single line of output, right? do you need to maintain the input file name with the matching output data and if the answer is 'yes' could you update the question to show the expected output with the (input) file names?

Comment: I don't need header and I don't need filename ; I have files, each made of structured list of lines : a=line1, b=line2, c=line3, etc., where I want to extract line2, line3 (I can do that with `awk '{print $2}' FS='=')`, but what I don't know how to do is have linedefaut value for files where, say, b=line2, is missing.

Comment: `awk '{print $2}' FS='='` will fail to print the whole value when the values themselves contain `=`. My answer shows you how to have default values where lines are missing and where values are missing.

Comment: At the final end, both answers given bellow do work with my test files and are equally better than everything I believed to be pretty close to my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed you said you only wanted to print the values for specific tags which makes things easier. Using GNU awk for `ENDFILE` and `gensub()`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS="\t"
    numTags = split("ctime rev targets name title",tags)

    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        tag = tags[tagNr]
        printf "%s%s", tag, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}

match($0,/^([[:alnum:]_]+)[=:](.*)/,a) {
    tag = a[1]
    val = gensub(" ?" OFS " ?"," ","g",a[2])
    tag2val[tag] = val
}

ENDFILE {
    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        tag = tags[tagNr]
        val = ( tag in tag2val ? tag2val[tag] : "_ABSENT_" )
        val = ( val == "" ? "_NULL_" : val )
        printf "%s%s", val, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    delete tag2val
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
ctime   rev     targets name    title
1041379201      3       Target.1,OtherTarget.23,Target.90       Name.12 My title
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s$'\t' -t
ctime       rev  targets                            name     title
1041379201  3    Target.1,OtherTarget.23,Target.90  Name.12  My title
```

---

Original answer:

It sounds like this might be what you're trying to do if the tags in each input file are unique, requiring GNU awk for several extensions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
match($0,/^([[:alnum:]_]+)[=:](.*)/,a) {
    tag = a[1]
    val = gensub(" ?" OFS " ?"," ","g",a[2])

    if ( !seen[tag]++ ) {
        tags[++numTags] = tag
    }

    key2val[ARGIND,tag] = val
}
END {
    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        tag = tags[tagNr]
        printf "%s%s", tag, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
    }

    for ( fileNr=1; fileNr<=ARGIND; fileNr++) {
        for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
            tag = tags[tagNr]
            key = fileNr SUBSEP tag
            val = ( key in key2val ? key2val[key] : "_ABSENT_" )
            val = ( val == "" ? "_NULL_" : val )
            printf "%s%s", val, (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
version agent   author  charset csum    ctime   description     host    name    rev     targets text    time    title   diff
_NULL_  _NULL_  _NULL_  _NULL_  _NULL_  1041379201      _NULL_  _NULL_  Name.12 3       Target.1,OtherTarget.23,Target.90       _NULL_   _NULL_  My title        _NULL_
```

To see the columns visually aligned:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s$'\t' -t
version  agent   author  charset  csum    ctime       description  host    name     rev  targets                            text    time    title     diff
_NULL_   _NULL_  _NULL_  _NULL_   _NULL_  1041379201  _NULL_       _NULL_  Name.12  3    Target.1,OtherTarget.23,Target.90  _NULL_  _NULL_  My title  _NULL_
```

Just run it on all of your files at once as:

```
awk -f tst.awk file1 file2 etc.
```

and it'll figure out all of the tags across all of your files then print a TSV with the values for all of those tags from all of those files.

Comment: I forgot to say I'm working with macos ; making proposed Ed's script failing : >>> match($0,/^([[:alnum:]_]+)[=:](.*)/, <<< 
awk: bailing out at source line 2 source file tst.awk

Comment: Then install gawk, it's easy to do (google it).

Comment: Gawk installed (easy when you know what not to do). Your script tested, working, but has to be refined for some source files (output may work ot not, depending on the source : I suspect the regex is not exactly the one I need). I have found an alternative awk solution which looks like better compatible with my project.

Comment: Honestly - I'm sorry but it's extremely unlikely that there's a better solution than this for the type of thing you're trying to do. The one you reference in your question certainly isn't as it'll be orders of magnitude slower, produce output in random order, can't differentiate between empty values and missing tags, would fail if your input contained tabs or `"`s, etc. If the regexp I used (which I created based on your example) isn't what you need then fix it or if you can use a `$1` as in that other answer, then just set FS like you would with that and use `$1` instead of `a[1]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- an input file has at least one line
- `field=value` entries do not span multiple lines (ie, neither `field` nor `value` include embedded linefeeds/carriage-returns)
- neither `field` nor `value` contain the `=` character (ie, `=` only shows up once per input line)
- OP can create a new file containing the list of desired fields and their default values [this eliminates the need to hardcode the field names, their order, and their default values]

Sample input files:

```
$ cat 1.txt
version=
agent=
author=
charset=
csum=
ctime=1041379201
description=
host=
name=Name.12
rev=3
targets=Target.1,OtherTarget.23,Target.90
text=
time=
title=My title
author:
csum:
diff:
host:
author:
csum:
diff:

$ cat 2.txt
version=pmwiki-2.2.64 ordered=1 urlencoded=1
author=simon
charset=UTF-8
csum=add summary
name=Main.HomePage
rev=203
targets=PmWiki.DocumentationIndex,PmWiki.InitialSetupTasks,PmWiki.BasicEditing,Main.WikiSandbox
text=(:Summary:The default home page for the PmWiki distribution:)%0aWelcome to PmWiki!%0a%0aA local copy of PmWiki's%0adocumentation has been installed along with the software,%0aand is available via the [[PmWiki/documentation index]].  %0a%0aTo continue setting up PmWiki, see [[PmWiki/initial setup tasks]].%0a%0aThe [[PmWiki/basic editing]] page describes how to create pages%0ain PmWiki.  You can practice editing in the [[wiki sandbox]].%0a%0aMore information about PmWiki is available from [[http://www.pmwiki.org]].%0a
time=1400472661

$ cat 3.txt                # NOTE: no matches with fields in defaults.txt
other=abc
line=def
```

Assuming OP can create a file containing the desired field names and default values, eg:

```
$ cat defaults.txt
ctime=CCCC
name=NNNN
rev=REV
targets=NO_TARGETS
title='BLANK TITLE'
```

**NOTE:** the order of the fields in the final output is the same as the order of the fields in `defaults.txt`

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -F'=' '

function print_line() {
    pfx=""
    if ( printme )                       # skip the first call to this function
       for ( i=1; i<=ordno; i++ ) {      # loop through our list of desired fields ...

           printf "%s%s", pfx, ( order[i] in fields ? fields[order[i]] : defaults[order[i]] )
           pfx=OFS
       }

    print ""                             # terminate line
    delete fields                        # reset our fields[] array
    printme=1                            # enable printing of fields[] contents on next call
}

BEGIN          { OFS="\t"                # output field delimiter
                 printme=0               # disable printing of fields[] on first function call
               }

FNR==NR        {                         # process 1st file, ie, our desired fields and their associated default values
                 order[++ordno]=$1       # save order of fields
                 defaults[$1]=$2         # save default values
                 next
               }

FNR==1         { print_line()            # upon seeing a new file flush the contents of fields[] to stdout
                 print "#### "FILENAME   # remove this line once OP validates output
               }

$1 in defaults { fields[$1]=$2 }         # if field #1 is in our default[] array then save field #2 in our fields[] array

END            { print_line() }          # flush last file/fields[] to stdout

' defaults.txt 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

**NOTE:** I don't have access to a MacOS/awk installation so OP will need to determine if this works in their environment

This generates:

```
#### 1.txt
1041379201      Name.12 3       Target.1,OtherTarget.23,Target.90       My title
#### 2.txt
CCCC    Main.HomePage   203     PmWiki.DocumentationIndex,PmWiki.InitialSetupTasks,PmWiki.BasicEditing,Main.WikiSandbox 'BLANK TITLE'
#### 3.txt
CCCC    NNNN    REV     NO_TARGETS      'BLANK TITLE'
```

And without the `print "#### "FILENAME`:

```
1041379201      Name.12 3       Target.1,OtherTarget.23,Target.90       My title
CCCC    Main.HomePage   203     PmWiki.DocumentationIndex,PmWiki.InitialSetupTasks,PmWiki.BasicEditing,Main.WikiSandbox 'BLANK TITLE'
CCCC    NNNN    REV     NO_TARGETS      'BLANK TITLE'
```

Comment: Script tested ; does work yet imperfectly for presentation (where I want existing ctime to be printed, I get default value CCCC ; and in case rev doesn't exist, title is melted (superposed) in middle of targets value + name is deleted by superposed default value REV).

Comment: My mistake : as for presentation, output sent in txt file does work (terminal broke the layout, sorry).

Comment: ctime does work as well as expected, when defaults.txt is corrected (typo) : ctime in place of cctime.